# Swift - UITableViewCell label position is shifted after scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview

The Table View Cells are laid out correctly during the initial load, but when I scroll up or down, the labels are shifted to the left.  I'm not sure what is going on here.

My code for the tableview cell is below.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let workout = self.workouts[indexPath.row] as? Workout
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WorkoutCell") as? WorkOutCell

    cell!.textCell?.text = workout?.title
    cell!.backgroundColor = workout?.color
    cell!.countLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row+1)"
    cell!.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    return cell!
}
```

Image:

[image]

Thanks much!

Comment: your code for tableViewCell seems correct. May be you can check the layout constraints for the two Labels you have in your tableviewcell

Comment: I've check my constraints and all seem to be working.  It looks like the constraint is wiped out when cells are dequeued, I'm now sure how to catch the new cell to manually reapply those constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any changes if use this instead?

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WorkoutCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? WorkOutCell
```